# How to link zziplib library to zlib and use it?

Tags: objective-c

I need to use functions of zziplib library. I installed it on my ubuntu machine using:

```
sudo apt-get install zziplib-bin
```

In the command line I link using `-lzzip -lz`. I also use `#include "zziplib.h"` in my code. I get an error saying "zziplib.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated."

Where am I going wrong?

TIA

Comment: You're linking just fine. Find out where the header file is and then include properly.

Comment: What Operating System?  I assume Linux?  Please tag as appropriate.

Comment: Yes Linux.I now get an error saying "cannot find -lzzip".I installed zziplib, still i see this.Any help?TIA